# Change TextureView Size at Runtime

Tags: java, android

I am working on streaming an mp4 to a textureView for an app I am currently working on. I have the TextureView displaying the video however I need to resize it to match the screen size on rotation. After much trial and error, it seems that the problem is that the TextureView cannot be made larger than the containing view. I have also tried to resize the container view but I am then unable to center the TextureView correctly on screen.

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    if(isLandscape(orientation)){
        myTexture.setRotation(-90);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.width = height;
        params.height = (height * 9)/16;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        

        myTexture.setLayoutParams(params);
        myTexture.getLayoutParams().height = (height * 9)/16;
        myTexture.getLayoutParams().width = height;

        rl.requestLayout();
        rl.invalidate();
        rl.recomputeViewAttributes(myTexture);

        Log.v("View Size", "Width tex: " + myTexture.getWidth());
        Log.v("View Size", "Height tex: " + myTexture.getHeight());
        Log.v("View Size", "Width tex parent: " + rl.getWidth());
        Log.v("View Size", "Height tex parent : " + rl.getHeight());

    }
}
```

My Xml file is below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
android:id="@+id/mediaParent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp">

<TextureView
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="203dp"
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This link :

http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/video-cropping-with-texture-view/21

```
private void initView() {
    mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    // SurfaceTexture is available only after the TextureView
    // is attached to a window and onAttachedToWindow() has been invoked.
    // We need to use SurfaceTextureListener to be notified when the SurfaceTexture
    // becomes available.
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    updateTextureViewSize((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY());
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void updateTextureViewSize(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using a framelayout fixed my issue.